# How to install Magento 2.1 to PostgreSQL

Tags: magento-2.1, database, installation, setup

As the topic. I would like to magento worked on PostgreSQL. Is it possible during installation instead of MySQL indicate PostgreSQL database?
Completely abandon MySQL. Only use PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Magento does not support Postgres, nor is it likely to in the foreseeable future. Besides the extensive core work that would likely be necessary, it would break many third party extensions that use direct SQL queries in the MySQL dialect.